# get image pixels into array

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

i am trying to rewrite following code from silverlight to wpf. found here https://slmotiondetection.codeplex.com/

my problem is that WritaeableBitmap.Pixels is missing from wpf. how to achieve that? i understand how it works but i started with C# like week ago.

could you please point me to right direction?

```
    public WriteableBitmap GetMotionBitmap(WriteableBitmap current)
    {
        if (_previousGrayPixels != null && _previousGrayPixels.Length > 0)
        {
            WriteableBitmap motionBmp = new WriteableBitmap(current.PixelWidth, current.PixelHeight);

            int[] motionPixels = motionBmp.Pixels;
            int[] currentPixels = current.Pixels;
            int[] currentGrayPixels = ToGrayscale(current).Pixels;

            for (int index = 0; index < current.Pixels.Length; index++)
            {
                byte previousGrayPixel = BitConverter.GetBytes(_previousGrayPixels[index])[0];
                byte currentGrayPixel = BitConverter.GetBytes(currentGrayPixels[index])[0];

                if (Math.Abs(previousGrayPixel - currentGrayPixel) > Threshold)
                {
                    motionPixels[index] = _highlightColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    motionPixels[index] = currentPixels[index];
                }
            }

            _previousGrayPixels = currentGrayPixels;

            return motionBmp;
        }
        else
        {
            _previousGrayPixels = ToGrayscale(current).Pixels;

            return current;
        }
    }
    public WriteableBitmap ToGrayscale(WriteableBitmap source)
    {
        WriteableBitmap gray = new WriteableBitmap(source.PixelWidth, source.PixelHeight);

        int[] grayPixels = gray.Pixels;
        int[] sourcePixels = source.Pixels;

        for (int index = 0; index < sourcePixels.Length; index++)
        {
            int pixel = sourcePixels[index];

            byte[] pixelBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(pixel);
            byte grayPixel = (byte)(0.3 * pixelBytes[2] + 0.59 * pixelBytes[1] + 0.11 * pixelBytes[0]);
            pixelBytes[0] = pixelBytes[1] = pixelBytes[2] = grayPixel;

            grayPixels[index] = BitConverter.ToInt32(pixelBytes, 0);
        }

        return gray;
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the bitmap's raw pixel data you may use one of the [`BitmapSource.CopyPixels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels.aspx) methods, e.g. like this:

```
var bytesPerPixel = (source.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
var stride = source.PixelWidth * bytesPerPixel;
var bufferSize = source.PixelHeight * stride;
var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
source.CopyPixels(buffer, stride, 0);
```

Writing to a `WriteableBitmap` can be done by one of its [`WritePixels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.writepixels.aspx) methods.

Alternatively you may access the bitmap buffer by the WriteableBitmap's [`BackBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.backbuffer.aspx) property.

For converting a bitmap to grayscale, you might use a [`FormatConvertedBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx) like this:

```
var grayscaleBitmap = new FormatConvertedBitmap(source, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, 0d);
```